# How do I separate finalizing into different databases in DataMapper?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

Currently in my Sinatra + DataMapper app, I have:

```
require 'data_mapper'

DataMapper.setup(:default,  "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/main.db")
DataMapper.setup(:comments, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/comments.db")

class Recording
    include DataMapper::Resource

    # ...

    belongs_to :user
    has n, :comments
end

class User
    include DataMapper::Resource

    # ...

    has n, :recordings
end

class Audience
    include DataMapper::Resource

    # ...
end

# -------- ITS OWN DATABASE --------
class Comment
    include DataMapper::Resource

    #...

    belongs_to :recording
end
```

I want the Comments class to go separately from the others into comments.db. I was looking around, and I saw something like this (and to which I have formatted to my situation):

```
# -------- ITS OWN DATABASE --------
repository(:comments) do 
    class Comment
        include DataMapper::Resource

        #...

        belongs_to :recording
    end
end
```

Would this work out as planned, or is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We override the `#default_repository_name` method on our models to do this:

```
class Comment
  include DataMapper::Resource

  def self.default_repository_name
    :comments
  end
end
```

Comment: And I would do this before `DataMapper.finalize ; DataMapper.auto_migrate!`?

Comment: Well, it's actually hard-coded into your models, so yes, before both of those two things.